# use part of JSON array in jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I have array like this:

```
var $styles = {

'Night': [{
    featureType: 'all',
    stylers: [
        { invert_lightness: 'true' }
    ]
}],

'Greyscale': [{
    featureType: 'all',
    stylers: [
        { saturation: -100 },
        { gamma: 0.50 }
    ]
}],}
```

At the input I get a string with name.
I want extract and insert part of this array calling name, like:

```
var $night = 'Night'; 
var $grayscale = 'Grayscale';

new Maplace({ 
  style: //insert here part of $styles with name from $night or $grayscale
})
```

I dont know how extract part of $styles with name

Comment: This is the sort of question that junks up the SOF database and could have been solved with a little learning / google..

Answer (score 1):

i guess you want this:

```
var $night = 'Night'; 
var $grayscale = 'Grayscale';

new Maplace({ 
  style: $styles[$night] // for night and for grayscale -> style: $styles[$grayscale]
})
```

---

And one thing to notice:

You have a typo in the json here `'Greyscale'` while in your var you have `'Grayscale'`.

---

***At the input I get a string with name. I want extract and insert part of this array calling name.***

So i guess you just need to use this way:

```
var $option = $('yourinput_id/class').val(); 

new Maplace({ 
  style: $styles[$option]
})
```